# Trouble changing databases for my models in codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, model

I'm making a website with two different databases.  Let's say one is DB1, and the other is DB2.  I've set up my database.php in the config folder, so they each have the correct host/password/username/database etc with db['DB1']['hostname'] and the other db['DB2']['hostname'] etc, so I'm pretty sure I've got that part right.

According to CodeIgniter docs, I'm supposed to do $this->load->database('DB1') to get that one to work within my model.  First, I put it in my constructor for my model, and it didn't work.  Then I tried putting that line as the first line of every function in the model, and that didn't work.  I'm still getting this error:

```
Error Number: 1146

Table 'DB2.stores' doesn't exist
```

When I'm trying to use DB1, and have done $this->load->database('DB1') as the first line of the model's function.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: There's something wrong with the setup. You shouldn't have any errors that say something about DB2 since this is not the actual database.

Comment: I'm just subbing in DB2.  It's actually "Table 'ethan_phorum.stores' doesn't exist", when I'm trying to get it to use my other DB.  Maybe if someone posted an example of them using multiple DBs in a model, I could copy it or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of caveats I ran into when I last tried to do that.

In your model constructor, load DB1 and DB2 as

```
$this->DB1=$this->load->database('DB1',true) //<-- notice the true parameter
$this->DB2=$this->load->database('DB2',true) //<-- notice the true parameter
```

and then use `$this->DB1->get()->where()->result_array()` etc.etc.

**Caveat 2**
make sure persistent connections are off... they are on by default in CI

```
$db['DB2']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

and

```
$db['DB2']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

in your application/config/database.php file

hope that helps...

Comment: I was missing the pconnects! Thank you!